# create function using one IN and 2 OUT parameters

Tags: oracle, function

I want to create a Oracle function which consists of one input parameters and 2 output parameters. So below is the code I wrote.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_CMM_REPORT
 (
  p_span_link_id IN nvarchar2,
  p_cmmapproved  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  p_cmm_tobe_approved  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) 
 RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
 BEGIN
  select ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM AS "CMM APPROVED" from TBL_FIBER_INV_CMPAPPROVED_INFO where 
 SPAN_LINK_ID= p_span_link_id
 and ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM > 0;

select NE_LENGTH
from TBL_FIBER_INV_CMPAPPROVED_INFO where SPAN_LINK_ID= p_span_link_id;
 RETURN NULL;
END GET_CMM_REPORT;
```

Is my function OK as I am new to create oracle function. Please suggest how to implement this.

Comment: Did you try compiling your code? If so, did you get any errors or unexpected results? (I can see that it looks like you're trying to return some ref cursors, but you haven't actually set up the ref cursors in the body of the code; you're missing some `open <ref cursor> for ....` statements.) As for how to implement it, that's a hard question for us to answer. How is it going to be called? From another PL/SQL procedure? From an application? Something else? We don't know your system, requirements or database!

Comment: In my opinion, switch to a **procedure**. Function with 2 OUT parameters that returns NULL (just to return *something*, as function that doesn't return *anything* is invalid) is useless.

Comment: @Boneist: yes it will be getting called from another procedure.. so how can I proceed with creating this function. Currently, I am getting issue as `INTO clause is expected into select statement`

Comment: @Boneist: I was just trying to implement like this by some google checks, but help me in the way it should be created so that I can call it from another stored procedure...

Comment: @Littlefoot: Please help me in doing it in **FUNCTION** only

Comment: Why is it so important that it be done in a function only?  That doesn't make a lot of sense.  It's possible, it just doesn't make sense (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be syntactically valid

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_CMM_REPORT
 (
  p_span_link_id IN nvarchar2,
  p_cmmapproved  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  p_cmm_tobe_approved  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) 
 RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
 BEGIN
    open p_cmmapproved for 
      select ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM AS "CMM APPROVED" 
        from TBL_FIBER_INV_CMPAPPROVED_INFO 
       where SPAN_LINK_ID= p_span_link_id
         and ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM > 0;

    open p_cmm_tobe_approved for 
      select NE_LENGTH
        from TBL_FIBER_INV_CMPAPPROVED_INFO 
       where SPAN_LINK_ID= p_span_link_id;
    RETURN NULL;
END GET_CMM_REPORT;
```

Logically, though, a function that has two `out` parameters and returns a hard-coded `null` is rather odd.  You'd be better off with a stored procedure instead

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_CMM_REPORT
 (
  p_span_link_id IN nvarchar2,
  p_cmmapproved  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  p_cmm_tobe_approved  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) 
 AS
 BEGIN
    open p_cmmapproved for 
      select ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM AS "CMM APPROVED" 
        from TBL_FIBER_INV_CMPAPPROVED_INFO 
       where SPAN_LINK_ID= p_span_link_id
         and ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM > 0;

    open p_cmm_tobe_approved for 
      select NE_LENGTH
        from TBL_FIBER_INV_CMPAPPROVED_INFO 
       where SPAN_LINK_ID= p_span_link_id;
END GET_CMM_REPORT;
```

Or create two separate functions that each return a single cursor.

Comment: just one more thing to ask related to this.. If u don't mind can I go ahead ?

Comment: I want to add 3rd out `sys_refcursor` whose query will come from **(2nd sys_refcursor - 1st sys_refcursor)** .. So how can implement this logic..!!

Comment: @hud - That doesn't make sense.  You can't open a `sys_refcursor` based on another `sys_refcursor`.  You could open a third cursor whose query happens to duplicate/ combine some or all of the logic from the queries used to open one or the other of the cursors.  But that would be a separate query with no reference to either of the other cursors.

Comment: oh... okay let me discuss with my team. thanks for the update though!!

Comment: one more thing, can we handle if **ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM or NE_LENGTH** for `p_span_link_id` does not has any row then by default it should consider it as `0` ?

Comment: @hud - I'm not sure that I understand the question. Does "consider it as 0" mean that you want to return a cursor that has a single row with a single column whose value is 0?

Comment: No, not a single row.. for ex:- I execute a select statement with where condition `p_span_link_id` returns nothing so for that `p_span_link_id` it should consider value as `ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM` = `0`

Comment: @hud - "Returns nothing" implies that no row is returned.  Do you really mean that `route_approved_by_cmm` and/or `ne_length` is `null` and you want to return 0 instead of `null`?  If so, just `coalesce( ne_length, 0 )`.

Comment: yes, I want that.. now you get it correctly

Comment: I made some minor changes accordingly after my discussion with manager, here is the link for the same. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e597dbb60a9c400efabbc160e68d7912 but getting error as `Error(11,24): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; not null range default character`

Comment: @hud - Creating a fiddle is nice but you have to create the table(s) your code relies on first.  Otherwise you can't usefully debug any code.  You've introduced a variety of errors.  Why on earth would you mark that function as deterministic?  You've changed the `out` parameters to numbers so you can't open a `sys_refcursor` with the results of a query.  You'd need to do a `select into` and you'd need to ensure that your queries always return exactly 1 row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233274/discussion-between-hud-and-justin-cave).

Comment: are u available on chat discussion ?